# Placeholder thumbnails are showing instead of product images in WooCommerce categories page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

placeholder thumbnails are showing instead of product images in woocommerce  categories page, this images shows all the products under the "Beauty and perfumes" category
[placeholder thumbnails shows instead of my product thumbnails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7QZ2.png)

but the image displays when i click on a specific product
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7QuJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had a plugin that had settings hiding the images inadvertently. 
To figure out the culprit I deactivated all my plugins.  The images were now showing. Next, I added re-activated them one by one until the placeholder images showed up again.  So now I knew what/who was causing the issue.

I then activated the offending plugin and went through its settings until I found a setting that turned off images.

In this case, it wasn't a bad plugin it was just user error.

Just in case you are using the same or similar plugin it was: "Easy Custom Auto Excerpt"

I hope this helps any future developer with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional info.
I came across with this issue just right now.

Please make sure to set the Primary image of the product otherwise it will show the placeholder and won't show the product image gallery too.